# Android Error: Attempt to invoke virtual... setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

My app closes and gives the error. Please help.

**Activity class**

```
public class MenuPrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button btcadastrar_ferramenta;
    Button btconsultar_ferramenta;
    Button btalterar_dados;
    Button btexcluir_ferramenta;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal);

        btcadastrar_ferramenta = (Button)
                findViewById(R.id.btcadastrar_ferramenta);
        btalterar_dados = (Button)
                findViewById(R.id.btalterar_dados);
        btconsultar_ferramenta = (Button)
                findViewById(R.id.btconsultar_ferramenta) ;
        btexcluir_ferramenta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btexcluir_ferramenta);
        btcadastrar_ferramenta.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent cadastrarFerramentaActivity = new
                        Intent(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, CadastrarFerramentasActivity.class
                );
                MenuPrincipalActivity.this.startActivity
                        (cadastrarFerramentaActivity);
                btalterar_dados.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent consultaFerramentaActivity = new
                                Intent(MenuPrincipalActivity.this,
                                BuscaFerramentasActivity.class);
                        consultaFerramentaActivity.putExtra("opcao_dados", 1);

                        MenuPrincipalActivity.this.startActivity(consultaFerramentaActivity);
                    }
                });


                btconsultar_ferramenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent consultaFerramentaActivity = new
                                Intent(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, BuscaFerramentasActivity.class);
                        consultaFerramentaActivity.putExtra("opcao_dados", 2);
                        MenuPrincipalActivity.this.startActivity(consultaFerramentaActivity);
                    }
                });
                btexcluir_ferramenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View argO) {
                        Intent consultaFerramentaActivity = new
                                Intent(MenuPrincipalActivity.this, BuscaFerramentasActivity.class);
                        consultaFerramentaActivity.putExtra("opcao_dados", 3);
                        MenuPrincipalActivity.this.startActivity(consultaFerramentaActivity);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    db = openOrCreateDatabase("banco_dados", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    db.execSQL("create table if not exists  " + "ferramentas(numreg integer primary key " +
                            "autoincrement, nome_ferramenta text not null," +
                            "fabricante text not null, " + "preco float not null," +
                            "cor text not null, referencia text not null)");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    MostraMensagem("Erro" + e.toString());
                }
            }

            public void MostraMensagem(String str) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuPrincipalActivity.this);
                dialogo.setTitle("Aviso");
                dialogo.setMessage(str);
                dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                dialogo.show();
            }

        } );}}
```

**CadastrarFerramentasActivity class**

```
public class CadastrarFerramentasActivity extends Activity {

    EditText ednome_ferramenta, edfabricante, edpreco, edcor, edreferencia;

    Button btcadastrar, btfechar;

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastrar_ferramentas);
        ednome_ferramenta= (EditText)
                findViewById(R.id. ednome_ferramenta);
        edfabricante = (EditText) findViewById(R. id .edfabricante);
        edpreco = (EditText) findViewById(R. id . edpreco);
        edcor = (EditText) findViewById(R. id.edcor);
        edreferencia = (EditText) findViewById(R. id .edreferencia);
        btcadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btcadastrar_ferramenta);
        btcadastrar .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                String nome_ferramenta = ednome_ferramenta. getText( ) . toString() ;
                String fabricante = edfabricante.getText() .toString();
                String preco = edpreco.getText() .toString() ;
                String cor = edcor.getText() .toString();
                String referencia = edreferencia.getText() . toString();
                ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
                valor. put ( "nome_ferramenta " , nome_ferramenta);
                valor. put ( "fabricante " , fabricante);
                valor. put ( "preco " , Float . parseFloat(preco));
                valor. put ("cor", cor) ;
                valor. put ( " referencia " , referencia) ;
                db. insert ( "ferramentas " , null, valor);
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new
                        AlertDialog.Builder  (CadastrarFerramentasActivity. this) ;
                dialogo. setTitle( "Aviso");
                dialogo. setMessage( "Dados cadastrados com sucesso! " ) ;
                dialogo. setNeutralButton( "OK" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override  public void onClick(DialogInterface argO, int argl) {
                                CadastrarFerramentasActivity.this.finish();
                            }});
                                dialogo. show( ) ;

                            }

    });
        btfechar = (Button) findViewById(R. id .btfechar); btfechar. setOnClickListener(new View. OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View argO) {
                CadastrarFerramentasActivity.this.finish();
            }});
                try {
                    db = openOrCreateDatabase("banco_dados",
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    MostraMensagem("Erro" + e.toString());
                }
            }

            public void MostraMensagem(String str) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastrarFerramentasActivity.this);
                dialogo.setTitle("Aviso");
                dialogo.setMessage(str);
                dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK ", null);
                dialogo.show();
            }
        }
```

**Error given is this:**

```
06-08 20:09:46.136 6894-6894/com.example.iohananabc.ferramentas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.iohananabc.ferramentas, PID: 6894
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iohananabc.ferramentas/com.example.iohananabc.ferramentas.CadastrarFerramentasActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
         at com.example.iohananabc.ferramentas.CadastrarFerramentasActivity.onCreate(CadastrarFerramentasActivity.java:33)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: At what line exactly in your code does this error occur? Please post the full logcat.

Comment: Can you also include your layout xml files for `CadastrarFerramentasActivity` activity? It might be because of the id you used in the `findViewById()` for `btcadastrar`. The layout you maybe referring to is different.

Comment: Seems like this is the button in question :`btcadastrar .setOnClickListener`. Check the id you're using for `findViewById`.

Comment: whats on line 33 in `CadastrarFerramentasActivity.onCreate` ?

Comment: the line 33 is:   btcadastrar .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener

Answer (score 1):

Pelo nome das classes acredito que você fale português, então o motivo é que um dos comandos findViewById() deve estar retornando nulo ou o cast está dando errado, então verifique se no arquivo de layout as ids dos botões estão corretas.

In case you don't speak Portuguese. What is happening is that one of the findViewById() commands is returning null or the cast operations is failing. So what you got to do is check your layout file to see if the button's ids are correctly set;

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been a while since I've asked for the xml layout, and still wasn't posted, I'm gonna go on ahead and post my analysis as an answer.

In your error log, it is pointing towards a `setOnClickListener()` having an NPE in your `CadastrarFerramentasActivity`, and as per the code snippet you provided, the only one calling it is `btfechar.setOnClickListener`.

One explanation as to why this is happenning is because your `findViewId()` is referencing to an id (in your code your using `R.id.btfechar`) that is not in the activity layout you set (which is `R.layout.activity_cadastrar_ferramentas`).

Do check out your layout xml file, and let me know what happens (preferrably, update your post).

Cheers!